# Web API suddenly returns 403 forbidden after a few successfull requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I've been working on an ionic application in combination with an ASP.NET Web API. I'm using that API for all the data transfer.

I have been experiencing a problem: after a few successful requests, the API suddenly returns 403 forbidden. It seems like the API has a limitation or something, because it happens when I do multiple requests in a really short time.

The strange thing about this problem is that if I run the Web API locally it works perfectly fine, but if I host it on an external IIS server this problem shows up after a few requests. I end the process on the server to fix it temporary.

I hope some of you guys know this problem.

This might fix a lot for me in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if Dynamic IP Restrictions (DIPR) module is installed on the external IIS server? http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/using-dynamic-ip-restrictions

Comment: I have no idea, I'm checking it right now

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.

Comment: I also see maximum number of requests and such things. And send 403. Looks like my problem.

Comment: If I want to change settings and I click apply I get the message: Could not read the configuration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was inside my IIS Manager for the ASP.NET Web API. I had to increase the limit of my Dynamic IP Restrictions (DIPR), because the API returned an 403 error after a few requests at the same time. When I increased the limited I noticed that the problem was fixed.

Comment: In IIS 8.0 and later this feature was renamed to "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" but the same settings still apply.  Max Calls Per X amount of time / Max concurrent requests from one IP.

Comment: Hi @Giovanni In my case also few web api requests are getting executed sucessfully and few are giving 403, I check my DIPR but there is no such limit applied on my webapi.
Basically this api is devolped by other team, so I am not getting how can I find the root cause behind this issue.

Comment: @Dreamer is the error generated by the endpoint?

Comment: yep, few requests are successful(around 100 request were successful) then 1 request giving forbidden, same scenario getting repeated.