# ASP.NET Identity Core cookie causes http 403 error when login and logout multiple time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, http-status-code-403, iis-10

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and it is hosted on shared hosting - IIS 10.
For authentication, I am using identity to check authentication.

I'm logging in and out multiple times in my application. After 6 or 7 attempts, it directs me to the 403 error page.

After clearing the cache from the browser, it works fine again.

Please assist me to find a solution.

I updated the machine key as well. still getting the same issue.

The error initiates from the dynamic compression module when we check the tracing

Comment: maybe this will give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/47263138/9936356

Comment: tried this one also. but still getting the same error.

Comment: For everyone else that might have this issue, for me, changing the identity cookie name at startup fixed the problem. (I have no idea how the name of the cookie can cause this error though)

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer from the Hosting team. They have installed (ModSecurity)WAF to block requests from understanding the behavior of requests. After disabling this works fine now.

It will definitely help someone.
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have any other background details to extend your response? In my case the hosting provider is not very helpful and don't want to adjust settings on their side given that it's a shared hosting environment.